# I can't select method on GameObject when Button Onclick in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lW2Nv.jpg)[enter image description here][2]How can I select the object here?

It was possible to do this in previous versions, but now I can't

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please correct the links and descriptive texts (instead of the default "enter image description here"). Also, please provide more information as to what the problem is and what you are trying to achieve. Please, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . This helps us ensure a proper answer to help you find a solution. Also, specify the current version and the "previous versions" where it was possible. What is the error you are getting? What steps did you try? What failed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply entered the Debug mode of the inspector. To get the visual layout that you're used to back, go back to the normal mode of the Inspector.

[image: Inspector mode]